# How to embed a Snap! Project into a website?

Tags: php

Is there any way to embed a snap project to a website in laravel?
If so, any links or even tutorials?

I can't seem to find it in the reference manual.

Comment: you might be better off with blocky?

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `<iframe>` that sources a Snap*!* project that was shared on the cloud. For example:

```
<iframe src="http://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html#present:Username=jens&ProjectName=PathFinder"></iframe>
```

The syntax for the URL is `http://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html#present:Username=<userName>&ProjectName=<projName>`.